# Calculated value for Single line of Text doesn't work

Tags: 2013, list, calculated-column

I have a column named "Risk" and the condition of the values is here:

> Düşük:  Risk <= 4
>
> Orta:   4 < Risk <8
>
> Yuksek: 8 <= Risk

Risk value is the sum of 2 column values.

> Risk value: [Column1] + [Column2]

The default value is calculated value:

> =IF( ([Etki]+[Olasılık])<=4, "Düşük", IF( ([Etki]+[Olasılık])>=8,
>   "Yüksek", "Orta") )

The type of "Risk" is Single line of text a but it doesn't work. It keeps saying **"The formula cannot refer to another column.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or update the formula to reference only this column.  "** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

goto the list settings page and do the calculation from there ;)

[image: column calculation list]

> In the Validation Settings link on the List Settings page, you can
>   validate one column against another. Here you can see that I’ve set
>   the [Due Date] > [Created].

[image]

that should work for you ;)

Comment: I selected Single line of text for column type and then I pasted the formula into the column validation part , I typed "Düşük" for the default value in Text radiobutton. Is it ok that I select Single line of text?

Comment: yes single line of text should be fine

Comment: Still this message occurs.The formula cannot refer to another column.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or update the formula to reference only this column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/844612f1-92ba-49a3-9f89-8013a558c999.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link is broken, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)